# Why I am getting error as "Error in mapIds(GeneCol) : could not find function "mapIds""

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, ensemble-learning

I am trying to get Entrez ID using a big list of Gene Symbol. To do this, I used "AnnotationDbi", "org.Hs.eg.db", and "org_pkg".

when I run the code as

**"geneIDs <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=rownames(Genename1), column=type, keytype=keys, multiVals="first")"**

I get the following error

**Error in mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = rownames(Genename1), column = type,  :
could not find function "mapIds"**

It would great if you can help me to overcome this problem. Alternatively, you can suggest to me how I can get Entrenz ID using gene symbol. Thank you in advance!

Best regards, Biswa

Answer (score 0):

have you load the 'org.Hs.eg.db' and AnnotationDbi  packages ?

```
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(AnnotationDbi)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I did and that problem has been solved, However, I got a new error "Error in testForValidKeytype(x, keytype) : 
  'keytype' must be a a single string"

Comment: This is because keytype require a single argument, you should run the code with keytype="SYMBOL"

Comment: Thank you Bastien for your nice help. I simply transfer the factor into the character and the problem has been solved and now I got my Entrez ID. :)